# Inequality regarding shortest cycle in graph

Tags: graph-theory

I came across a problem relating to cycles in graphs. Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph and denote the length of the shortest cycle by $g(G)$ (if $G$ has no cycles, then this value is set to infinity). For two nodes $x,y\in V$ we define $d(x,y)$ as the length of the shortest path between them (again, it is set to infinity, if there is no path between $x$ and $y$) and $D(G):=\max_{x,y\in V} d(x,y)$. I want to prove now, that we have
\begin{align*}
g(G) \leq 2D(G) +1
\end{align*}
in every graph that has cycles. Can anyone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to think of it as
$$
D(G) \geq \frac{g(G)-1}{2}.
$$
(And assume $G$ has a cycle.  It's not true for trees, where $D(G)$ is finite and $g(G)$ is infinite.)

Basically, we take the shortest cycle (which has $g(G)$ vertices, by definition), and show that it has two vertices $x$ and $y$ of distance $\frac{g(G)-1}{2}$ apart (and this is the greatest distance in the cycle).  If $G$ has any "shortcuts" between $x$ and $y$, it can be used to construct a cycle on fewer than $g(G)$ vertices, giving a contradiction.

Comment: apparently you mean inequality $D(G)\geq(g(G)-1)/2$.

Comment: @kabenyuk Oops, thanks!

Comment: thanks, I think I solved it now

Answer (score 0):

Let $K=(x_0,\dots,x_{g(G)-1})$ be a shortest cycle. We define $k:=\big\lfloor\frac{g(G)}{2}\big\rfloor$, $x=v_0$ and $y=v_k$. The shortest path from $x$ to $y$ has to be $(x,v_1,\dots, v_{k-1}, y)$ with length $k$ or else we could build a shorter cycle. The path $(y, v_{k+1},\dots, v_{g(G)-1}, x)$ has the same length or is 1 longer, depending on the parity of $g(G)$. We get
\begin{align*}
    g(G) \leq 2 d(x,y) + 1 \leq 2 D(G) + 1.
\end{align*}